# Passing arguments to sAjaxSource in jQuery datatables

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, jquery, datatables

I am working with CodeIgniter and I have the following problem.

I have a controller function in `details.php` which takes an argument:

```
function details($id) {
    $this->datatables
         ->select('product_id, original_amount, quantity')
         ->from('orders');

    echo $this->datatables->generate();
}
```

Now I need to call this from views, i.e. I want DataTables to display it like so:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() 
  $('#example').dataTable({
    ...
    'sAjaxSource' : 'admin/data/details',
    ...
  });
</script>
```

So, how do I pass arguments to the `sAjaxSource` key, namely the `$id` variable?

Comment: why you want to pass id in details method

Comment: instead of passing as arguments use post or get method

Comment: sir i want to do where('product_id',$id) in details method so i want to pass the value

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You should use `fnServerParams` as specified in the [docs](http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/server_side/custom_vars.html).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "scripts/server_processing.php",
        "fnServerParams": function ( aoData ) {
            aoData.push( { "name": "more_data", "value": "my_value" } );
        }
    } );
} );
```

Comment: i'm getting the error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined. Why ?

Comment: i am also getting same error " Cannot read property 'match' of undefined." can you provide some hint why this error getting using your solution

Comment: you have to enter the data as an arraylike: aoData.push( { "name": "name1", "value": "val1" } ,{ "name": "name2", "value": "val2" },{ "name": "name3", "value": "val3" });

Answer (score 3):

I was struggling with this issue myself. The answer of John Moses didn't work for me, also the link he provides links to the new documentation which, I think, does not count for older versions of datatables.

Although, I found out that the current server side processing is working like jQuery, where older versions with "sAjaxSource" don't work that way.

For me, I just simpely added my parameters in the url of the `sAjaxSource`. So in your example code:

```
$customPHPvar = "mycustomvar";

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "scripts/server_processing.php?customvar=<?php echo $customPHPvar; ?>",
    } );
} );
</script>
```

in server_processing.php

```
$_GET['customvar'];
```